# How to find the minimum score of each user from a list of maps using Java 8 stream

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Assuming I have the following list of maps,

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> scores = new ArrayList<>();

scores.add(Collections.singletonMap("user1", 3));
scores.add(Collections.singletonMap("user3", 15));
scores.add(Collections.singletonMap("user1", 1));
scores.add(Collections.singletonMap("user2", 5));
scores.add(Collections.singletonMap("user2", 23));
scores.add(Collections.singletonMap("user1", 10));
```

I would like to extract the minumum score of each user into a map using Java 8 stream with lambda expressions.  The desired result would be

```
{user1=1, user2=5, user3=15}
```

I tried this and it doesn't work,

```
Map<String, Integer> result = scores.stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))));
```

Could anyone please tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Map<String, Integer> result = 
    scores.stream()
          .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                                    Math::min));
```

Answer (score 5):

The `minBy` downstream collector returns `Optional<Entry<String, Integer>>`, but you need simply `Integer`. So you should use [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) to adapt a downstream collector. Also consider using [`Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--) static method.

```
Map<String, Integer> result = scores
        .stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.minBy(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()),
                opt -> opt.get().getValue())));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, without using streams, but with Java 8 features:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
scores.forEach(map -> map.forEach((k, v) -> result.merge(k, v, Integer::min)));
```

This uses the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method to select the minimum value for an already existent key.